# Send Email From Website To My Gmail PHP (405 method not allowed)

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up a personal portfolio and I want visitors to be able to contact me with job offers or questions. I haven't done much web development so I'm a bit stuck on why I can't receive this email. This is what I am using.

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'mrosborne16@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Comment: Where are you testing?

Comment: If you are testing in localhost the maill() function is disabled.
On another basis, why not use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Comment: I'm at my office? Right now the site is just a github.io site. Once I buy a domain tomorrow I will have it hosted on a server though.

Comment: Oh I didn't understand what Arkadi was asking. I tried in localhost and realized that mail probably wouldn't work and tried it live and didn't work there either. I haven't heard of PHPMailer but I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github Pages does not run server-side scripts (such as PHP). You will need to upload this script to a web host to run it.

Comment: Thanks duskwuff! I'll be putting this on a server in the near future. Glad to know this!